# Why do Ruby strings change by value with one operation and by reference with another

Tags: ruby

The following code:

```
 test_1 = "my test string"
 test_2 = test_1
 test_2[3] = "B"
 puts test_1
 puts test_2

 test_1 = "my test string"
 test_2 = test_1
 test_2 = test_2 + ""
 test_2[3] = "B"
 puts test_1
 puts test_2
```

produces the following result:

```
 my Best string
 my Best string
 my test string
 my Best string
```

Can some explain to me why in the first case both strings are altered (as though test_2 is being assigned by reference) but in the second case only test_2 changes (as though by value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the clarification :

```
test_1 = "my test string"
test_2 = test_1

test_2.object_id # => 83607730
test_1.object_id # => 83607730

test_2 = test_2 + ""

test_2.object_id # => 83606390
test_1.object_id # => 83607730
```

[`String#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-2B) created a new object. 
Thus `test_2[3] = "B"` added `"B"` to the new object referenced by `test_2`.It wouldn't change the object,whose reference is horded by `test_1`. Which is not the case in below :

```
test_1 = "my test string"
test_2 = test_1

test_2.object_id # => 70466640
test_1.object_id # => 70466640
```

Here `test_2` and `test_1` both holds the reference to the same object. Thus when you are doing `test_2[3] = "B"`,it is basically doing change in the same object which is referenced by the local variables `test_1` and `test_2`.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense. Still seems counter-intuitive though.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare `"test"` in Ruby, this creates a new String object.

```
"test".object_id   # => 9157960
"test".class       # => String
```

And when you assign a string to a variable, you point the variable to the string object on the other side of the assignment.

Take a look at the following:

```
# Point variable to first String object.
a = "test"         # => "test"
a.object_id        # => 9307800

# Point variable to second String object.
b = "test"         # => "test"
b.object_id        # => 9307760
a.equal?(b)        # => false

# Point variable to first String object.
c = a              # => "test"
c.object_id        # => 9307800
a.equal?(c)        # => true
```

So when you manipulate `a` here, you manipulate the object where `c` points.

Comment: In combination with the explanation above I now understand in more detail what is going on thanks to your explanation, so I've up-voted by 1.